# Marketing Cloud Security Settings API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I'm new to Marketing Cloud, coming from Salesforce.  In Salesforce there is a very good API for security settings, even if some of it needs to come via SOAP API.
In Marketing Cloud I couldn't locate any endpoint for the Security Settings such as Session Settings or Data Export Settings.

Am I missing some endpoint? Is there a secret endpoint for this? Or does Marketing Cloud just not support any machine access?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  The SFMC APIs are poorly documented and the permissions model is convoluted, so if you could narrow your ask, we may be able to suggest a path for you.

Comment: Hi @AdamSpriggs. I want to be able to monitor my SFMC Security Settings from multiple tenets in one source. To make sure for example that my organization session settings are set the same in all tenets, and to be able to alert if someone changes it.

Answer (score 2):

The full list of Marketing Cloud APIs can be found here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/apis-overview.html

Most of what you see in the Admin/Setup sections of Marketing Cloud is covered by SOAP API and there are SOAP objects related to [Users](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/useraccess.html), [Permissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/permissionset.html) and [Data Extracts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/creating_a_data_extract_activity_with_the_soap_web_service_api.html). There are also some [Platform](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/routes.html#platform) and [Setup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/routes.html#setup) routes available via REST API, but indeed there aren’t any related to Session Settings or other security settings.

Even if you run into any undocumented SFMC API endpoints, I wouldn’t recommend using them for any permanent solutions, as they might get shut down at any time without warning.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that you are unaware of any security settings API endpoints. Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem! And if this helped, please remember to accept the answer by ticking the checkbox - thanks!